# How to create hostname alias WITHOUT IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hostname, domain-name, amazon-rds

In linux , `/etc/hosts` stores ip aliases.

But I want to create a hostname without knowing its IP address.
In Amazon RDS , it's endpoint is a long domain name such as : `my-db.ooxxooxxooxxoo.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com` . It doesn't suggest connecting by IP (because it may change).

In such situation , how do I resolve a simple `db` string to this domain name ? WITHOUT any outer help , such as DNS CNAME or Route53 solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setup a local nameserver (eg `dnsmasq`) and insert the `CNAME` records you need into that.

dnsmasq.conf:

```
cname=alias,horrible-long-hostname.example.com
```

resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: CNAME stands for canonical name, aka an alternate name. So you could configure my-db.mydomain.com as a CNAME for my-db.ooxxooxxooxxoo.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com, and no matter what IP address Amazon sets db.ooxxooxxooxxoo.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com to, your CNAME alias will resolve to the same IP address.

Comment: Note that this _only_ works for targets which are names from DHCP or /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are trying to do is simplify ssh'ing to that system, you can use an ssh config file.  Create and edit ~/.ssh/config to contain:

`Host db:
     Hostname my-db.ooxxooxxooxxoo.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

After that, a simple "ssh db" will lookup what's specified in your .ssh/config file and connect you.

Comment: This solutiuon also covers rsync and scp.

Comment: no , I am not trying to do ssh. I want resolve to IP (used in JDBC connecting)

Comment: You may be able to add: search ooxxooxxooxxoo.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com to /etc/resolv.conf and then connect to my-db...